# Why does the view property have to be assigned to a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest

In the following code if I comment out the variable assigned to the view property, the tests fail.  The line I'm referring to is:

```
_=sut.view
```

However when that line of code is uncommented, the tests pass.  Why is it even necessary?

Here is the full unit test:

```
import XCTest
@testable import ToDo

class ItemListViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut:ItemListViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        sut = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController

        _=sut.view

    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }
    func test_TableViewIsNotNilAfterViewDidLoad(){
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.tableView.dataSource)
        XCTAssertTrue(sut.tableView.dataSource is ItemListDataProvider)

    }

    func testViewDidLoad_ShouldSetTableViewDelegate(){
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.tableView.delegate)
        XCTAssertTrue(sut.tableView.delegate is ItemListDataProvider)
    }

    func testViewDidLoad_ShouldSetDelegateAndDataSourceToSameObject(){
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.tableView.dataSource as? ItemListDataProvider, sut.tableView.delegate as? ItemListDataProvider)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View controllers don't load their view until the first time the `view` property is accessed, so assigning the `view` to a variable will load it.

If the view isn't loaded then none of the outlets will be hooked up so `sut.tableView` will be `nil` and your tests will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The `view` of a controller is loaded lazily the first time you are accessing it (automatically calling `UIViewController.loadView` and then `UIViewController.viewDidLoad`).

> If you access this property and its value is currently nil, the view controller automatically calls the loadView method and returns the resulting view.
>
> Because accessing this property can cause the view to be loaded automatically, you can use the isViewLoaded method to determine if the view is currently in memory. Unlike this property, the isViewLoaded property does not force the loading of the view if it is not currently in memory.

(from [UIViewController.view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/view))

Loading the controller view means that all its subviews are loaded and connected to outlets, therefore if you don't load the view, the `tableView` outlet will be `nil`.

Assigning to `_` is there only to silence the compiler warning about unused result. On iOS 9 and higher you can achieve the same using `sut.loadViewIfNeeded()`